# WCF Cache vs. Page.Cache

Tags: asp.net, wcf, caching

I've got two different, but closely related ASP.Net web applications that use the same data on some pages. In both applications I am using the ObjectDataSource control, have EnableCaching="true", and use the same CacheKeyDependency value in both applications.

I would like to make it so that when a new record is inserted or deleted in one application, it clears the cache in both applications. I began by simply clearing cache by using Page.Cache, but soon realized that it does not clear the cache in the other application. Then I added a WCF service to each application; each service clears the cache object in the application it is hosted in. Except that it doesn't...

First, I discovered that System.Web.HttpContext is always null in WCF. Then I tried instantiating a System.Web.Routing.RequestContext object, but its HttpContext object is always null as well.

It all boils down to this: If I set a Page.Cache object, can a WCF service access that same cache object, if the service is hosted in the same application as the page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you need to enable ASP.NET integration for the WCF service. This involves setting the `aspNetCompatibilityEnabled` attribute for the `serviveHostingEnvironment` element in config as well as adding the `AspNetCompatibilityRequirementAttribute` attribute to you service class to indicate that you support it.

More on this subject can be found [here on MSDN.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702682.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The main challenge with cache in two applications is that the cache can be stored on seperate machines, or if they are on the same machine, in different application pools.

One way you can do this is to allow both applications to use the same cache. One solution for a distributed cache that runs out of process is [Appfabric caching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsserver/ee695849).

Comment: Yeah, in my case it's definitely not worth getting into something like AppFabric. I've spent enough time on this already; I will just have to stop caching, or set the cache expiration very low, like a minute or two. Thanks though!